# Is this an efficient use of delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a while loop that needs to call one of two methods; which method will be called is based on a property of the objects being iterated over. Rather than doing a `if` / `switch` statement on this property, I have used delegates to do the `switch` statement outside the while loop.

This is easier to explain with code.

```
public void Plan()
{
   foreach (var itemHeader in estimate.ItemHeaders)
   {
      var scheduleMethod = new Schedule(ScheduleWall);

      switch (itemHeader.Type)
      {
         case TypeEnum.Stair: { scheduleMethod = new Schedule(ScheduleWall); break; }
         case TypeEnum.Wall: { scheduleMethod = new Schedule(ScheduleStair); break; }
      }

      foreach (var item in itemHeader.EstimateItems)
      {
         // this loop will run many, many times
         scheduleMethod(item);
      }
   }
}

private delegate void Schedule(EstimateItem item);

private void ScheduleWall(EstimateItem item)
{
   // do stuff..
}

private void ScheduleStair(EstimateItem item)
{
   // do stuff..
}
```

The alternative to calling the delegate inside the loop over `itemHeader.EstimateItems` would be to do the `switch` statement inside that loop. It's only compare two enums, but since that loop will run many times, it seems more efficient to do the comparison once, before the loop.

Am I introducing needless complexity? Is this a bad practice use of delegates?

Comment: I think this question would be better off at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @EricWu Code Review doesn't accept hypothetical/stub code though. Please familiarize yourself with the CR [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page before making such suggestions.

Comment: Sorry @Sam, I thought it was _not_ hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method in this case would be without delegates:

```
public void Plan()
{
   foreach (var itemHeader in estimate.ItemHeaders)
   {
      if(itemHeader.Type == TypeEnum.Wall)
         foreach (var item in itemHeader.EstimateItems)
            ScheduleStair(item);
      else
         foreach (var item in itemHeader.EstimateItems)            
            ScheduleWall(item);
   }
}
```

This way you are directly calling the method and it can even be inlined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting downvoted to hell for this question, so I take that as an indicator that this isn't a good use of delegates..